# Bootstrap Alert causes whitespace to appear

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

So, I'm currently creating a simple support center in HTML. Everything was going well until I added an bootstrap alert. When I added the alert in `col-lg-4` within the code (see bootsnipp), it generated a whitespace under the `Popular Support Topics` section.

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/r8xoj

Is there a way to remove this whitespace when the bootstrap alert is present and if there is more content within the `col-lg-4` code?

Comment: Try giving `col-md-12` to your `Popular Support Topics`

Comment: you should put all the left side content inside one "col-lg-8" div and right side contents inside one  "col-lg-4" div. so that both will grow height-wise independently without disturbing the adjacent columns.

These links must help you to study Nesting Columns: (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting)
(https://teamtreehouse.com/community/nesting-columns-in-bootstrap-3)

Comment: @vishnu Tried that, it just mixes everything up.

Comment: Here is working bootsnipp http://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/a2lA0

Comment: @vishnu That works! Thank you so much. Feel free to post this as an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This has been answered by [@vishnu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3554107/vishnu) within the comments:

> Here is working bootsnipp http://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/a2lA0